# Pythonic way to intersect with unknown number of parameters

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have to make a QuerySet.intersection() between an unknown number of parameters.

Is there a better way to write the following code ?

```
profileQuerySetList = None
for tag_id in current_tags:
    if profileQuerySetList:
        profileQuerySetList = profileQuerySetList & Profile.objects.filter(tags__id=tag_id)
    else:
        profileQuerySetList = Profile.objects.filter(tags__id=tag_id)
profiles = Profile.objects.intersection(profileQuerySetList)
```

Comment: So you want to obtain the `Profile`s that have all the given tags?

Comment: Indeed I want Profiles that have all the tags to restrict the number of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `intersection` method can take multiple querysets as arguments, using a generator expression, you can perform the same with:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.intersection(*(Profile.objects.filter(tags__id=tag_id) for tag_id in current_tags))
```

Comment: I like your solution and it's the way I wanted it. Can you explain or give me a link about the usage of the * in this situation ? Thanks.

Comment: `*` is Python's [unpack operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), which unpacks an iterable into individual items in that iterable. In this case it unpacks the querysets from the generator expression and pass them individually to the `intersection()` method.

Answer (score 0):

For me a better way, is the one that fulfil your requirements. But I think it is better and more pythonic to write it like making use of `in` operator.

`profiles = Profile.objects.intersection(Profile.objects.filter(tags__id__in=current_tags))`

As mentioned in the comment this `Profile.objects.filter(tags__id__in=current_tags)` will return union of objects.

I think another way is to make use of `Q` operator and write something like:

```
queries = [Q(tags__id=id) for id in current_tags]
query = queries.pop()
for q in queries:
    query &= q
profiles = Profile.objects.intersection(Profile.objects.filter(q))
```

Comment: By using the `in` operator, you're going to find a *union* of `Profile`s that have the given tags. That is, it will return `Profile`s with *any* of the given tags, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Your solution works too but doesn't differ a lot from mine.